# How to modify the curvature of edge line in cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to modify the curvature of edge between two nodes.
I know there is a function "curve-style". but as it says "The curving method used to separate two or more edges between two nodes".

In my case, there is only one single edge between two nodes.

Is there any way that I can define the curvature like in "curvature " property in cytoscape web?

Comment: I am imagining that you will need to modify the core code. I am wanting to do the same, if I come up with a solution I will let you know.

Answer (score 2):

You use `curve-style: bezier` for curved edges automatically spaced and `curve-style: unbundled-bezier` for complete manual control.

See http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-line

These properties are also of note for controlling the curve itself:

control-point-step-size : From the line perpendicular from source to target, this value specifies the distance between successive bezier edges.

control-point-distance : Overrides control-point-step-size with a manual value. Because it overrides the step size, bezier edges with the same value will overlap. Thus, it's best to use this as a one-off value for particular edges if need be.

control-point-weight : Weights control points along the line from source to target. This value ranges on [0, 1], with 0 towards the source node and 1 towards the target node.